# database structure for unconstant items

Tags: database, orm, database-schema

I have a database which own events as following :

```
event(id, name, type, startDate, endDate)
```

The type is another custom object (`Type(id, name, icon)`) which is linked as one-to-many.

I want to add another custom object named EventDetail containing details, but the fields would be different with the type of the event.

For instance, if my event is a travel type, fields could be a weblink to the wikipedia of destination, a photo, but if event is an internship for work they would evidently be different.

**What kind of structure could handle this type of situation ?**

If it is important, I'm using java for android, with an ORM library named SugarORM

### Final answer

I finally headed to ORM libraries for managing my database. Using a one-to-one relation between Type and EventDetail and one-to-many between Type and Event, it works really well for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go a few different ways with this...

One would be to create a catch-all table for `EventDetail` that has every field would need for every `type` and use the `type` to determine which fields you read from in that table.

Another way, if you do not have a lot of different types, would be to create a table for each type that would be structured to the needs of that type, in your queries, you would need to join to each of the tables based on the type (probably with using `UNION [ALL]`, one query per `type` - or create views).

A third, and probably more ideal depending on the situation and use, would be to remove that level of complexity from the database. Store your "Event Details" as a `CLOB` or `BLOB` or `XMLTYPE`, etc... and use the `type` to deserialize the data to an object on the client side.

Comment: Thanks ! I thought of the 2 first ways, but idealy the user should be able to add a type himself. I'll search for clob and blob since I don't know these.

Comment: The third way is probably the most robust way to implement what it appears you are attempting to do. It seems that these `EventDetail` items are not related to the functionality of the database, but are related to the client UI application. In which case, if everything has been stored correctly, you can reconstruct on the client side using the `type` and the serialized `EventDetail` data by serializing it back into the proper class/struct.

Comment: I just thought about another way : `EventDetail(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, ...)` and  `EventDetailParam(type, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, ...)`. Then programmatically I can construct my eventdetail with named parameter, but with a different constructor for each type. What do you think about this ?

Comment: The main question is, does the database need that level of complexity. Will these types/details be used/constructed anywhere within the database in anything more than an informational way, or are these objects strictly for operational use within the UI?

Comment: For now, I don't know yet, I think my app on step after another, so I want the more flexibility in case I want to do other things with these details later.